# android -How to save sliding tab content

Tags: android

I've a slidingTab in my application, it has 4 childs and each child connects to one fragament and get's data from json .

when I scroll from tab to tab ,it gets the data from internet and show them to me , it ok but How can I save the downloaded data and shows it again when I get back to the same tab ?

The problem is , it calls and gets data from internet every time I switch tabs and it's very bothering .

How can I save the tabs content and show them offline when it once's loaded ?

this is the code I use for creating tabs :

```
class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[]{"tab", "tab","tab","tab"};
    private Context context;

    public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        if (position == 0) {
            fragment = new Fragments();
            bundle.putString("for", "basteVije");
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        }
        if (position == 1) {
            fragment = new Fragments();
            bundle.putString("for", "topSold");
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        }
        if (position == 2) {
            fragment = new Fragments();
            bundle.putString("for", "jadidtarin");
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        }

        if (position == 3) {
            fragment = new Fragments();
            bundle.putString("for", "Pishnahad");
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
}

private void makeTabs() {
    viewpager.setAdapter(new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), FistActiivty.this));
    viewpager.setCurrentItem(4);
    // Give the SlidingTabLayout the ViewPager
    SlidingTabLayout slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    // Center the tabs in the layout
    slidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
    slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(viewpager);
    slidingTabLayout.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return Color.RED;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
viewpager.setOffScreenPageLimit(4);
```

The number depends on the number of tabs you want to set.

Answer (score 0):

you can save the result of your network request into [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Write the data:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString(FRAGMENT_ID, result);
editor.commit();
```

Read the data:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String result = sharedPref.getString(FRAGMENT_ID);
```

In this way you can decide if take data from locale or from network